# NSDateFormatter producing (null) - why?

Tags: ios5, nsdateformatter

I know there is a lot of threads on this subject and I have read them all.
Googled like crazy, read my books, but still (null) is the only thing I get.
So as my last hope and only hope I turn to you.

1) publicationDate is a NSString.
At this givven moment is holding this: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 19:46:00 +01:00

I do this to it:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:publicationDate];
NSLog(@"outDate: %@", date);
```

outDate says (null) and after way to many hours on this I give up.
I have no clue what is going on. I thought I did but no.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you date format is incorrect. Please try this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd LLL YYYY HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reformat this date from one format to another format, then you need to do this in two steps.

First convert to a date using a format mask that matches the input format, then convert back to a string using a format that matches the output format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put an `NSLog` for `publicationDate` in that code and there is a very good chance the problem will be clear.  You're code looks OK, I think, so chances are the problem is in the data, i.e. in `publicationDate`.
2. Side note: You don't want `YYYY`.  You want `yyyy`.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! Many of you have pointed me in the right direction.
Especially the last two people.

I have made in two steps now and included the correction of the format.